# Use a variable to set array length

Tags: c++, string, variables, set, constants

I am working on a scanning system to make edits to very long strings. For the scanning, I am using a string to contain the current letters being checked. I need to set the length of a `char[]` array to the length of the `string` variable, but my length variable is not considered a constant even though it is declared as `const`.

```
string inputScan;
cout << "Enter string." << endl;
getline(cin, inputScan);
const int stringLength = inputScan.length();
char scanSet[stringLength];
```

Any fixes?

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: It's not a compile-time constant, which is what is required to dimension an array. Also, if you have already read the string, why do you need another array?

Comment: It needs to be a compile-time constant. Try using a std::string instead: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: What does it mean to "set the length of the string"?  Isn't the length changed by changing the string itself, in a manner you have not described?

Comment: The second string has a single letter of the string as each item, so I can easily delete the last one, move them all down a space, and add another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed-length array dimensions need to be specified *at compile time*, so the compiler can allocate space for them (on the stack, or wherever). Therefore, your approach cannot work.

Use the C++ standards, like `std::vector`, and you will have no problems.

Comment: I'd drop "on the stack" because you don't really need to say it and, though unlikely, there might not be a stack.

Comment: Also, they might be allocated statically.

Comment: Or, replace `char scanSet[]` with `std::string scanSet`, or just get rid of `scanSet` altogether and scan `inputScan` directly.